# Работа с Perl в Windows 7

Tags: active-perl, perl

Нужна помощь. Всем Hi! Решил самостоятельно изучать Perl. Скачал несколько книг, скачал ActivePerl-5.14.2. У меня ось: Windows 7. Интерпретатор устанавливается нормально, проблем не возникает. Они появляются сразу, как только пытаюсь запустить любой скрипт, даже самый простейший. Появляется окошко DOS, и тут же пропадает. Я так понимаю, скрипт выполняется и сразу поисходит завершение программы. Что делать, чтоб этого не происходило? Менять Ось на Linux?

Comment: Кстати, переход на Linux - хорошая идея

Comment: как минимум три жирных плюса

 - адекватная консоль
 - нет проблем с кодировкой/русскими буквами
 - все таки перл к Linux ближе, чем к Windows

Comment: Скажем шире - к юниксу.

Answer (score 3):

Пуск -> Выполнить -> "cmd"

Comment: OR win+R =)

Answer (score 1):

Та же проблема, что и с другими языками. Можно сделать в конце программы пустой запрос на чтение с клавиатуры. Тогда программа остановится и будет ждать нажатия Enter.

Answer (score 1):

В конце скрипта можно написать:

```
<>;
```

Тогда программа остановится и будет ждать нажатия Enter, как уже написал **mikillskegg**.
Ещё есть один неплохой [IDE DzSoft Perl Editor](http://www.dzsoft.com/perl-editor.html), но он платный :-(.

Answer (score 0):

Установить себе IDE, для начала будет самое оно.
Например [padre](http://padre.perlide.org/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

Запускаю из Far и горя не знаю.
Особенно если запускать через .bat такого содержания:
perl script.pl
Разумеется перловый екзешник в путях виден д.б.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую SciTe от Руборда, так там автоматически подтягивается перл, можно как выполнять скрипт, так и проверять, результат будет в диалоговом окне програмы виден.